# Can we show database in row and column like phpAdmin in wamp ? (db in DDMS) android

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, ddms

I pulled file database from device (DDMS) and I don't know how to show it like row and column.

Anyone have idea, tell me please.

like this

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to browse it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to browse the database file. You can use http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

Answer (score 1):

For browsing sqlite database pulled from device, you can use Mozilla FireFox browser's plug-in, like this:-

```
        Click on the **FireFox** --> **Web Developer** --> **Sqlite Manager**.
```

Sqlite Manager will get open, then click on the **connect database** item in the **Database** menu to include your database for browsing.

Answer (score 0):

While these programs work for viewing a SQLite database file, the bigger issue on Android is that you need to root your phone or use the emulator if you want to actually pull the file onto your computer.